# Reliable Binance Smart Chain Node End Point

Tags: binance-smart-chain, binance-api-client

I am looking to get a end point for BSC (BNB) chain, any reliable providers? I tried with Moralis Speedy nodes, but it frequently gets disconncted if I use it in a node js program. I am using a wss connection to check pending txs.

Any other reliable providers?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

You can run your own Binance Smart Chain (BNB Chain) node for the maximum reliability.

[Here are some misc. instructions](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/ethereum-blockchain-docker-compose/#bsc-further-info), but better to follow BNB Chain official guide how to run a node.